# Why is my Cursor for loading images from external storage empty

Tags: android, image, kotlin, indexoutofboundsexception, android-cursor

I keep getting an empty cursor with this method used for loading external images, no idea why. It also worked for me on one emulator configuration before, but now when I try to Log the contents of ID it says:
**android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0**. There's pictures installed on the emulator in 3 different external directories.

```
private suspend fun loadImages(): List<Image>
    {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val uri = if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
                MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)
            } else MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            requireActivity().contentResolver.query(uri, arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID),
                null, null, "${MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED} ASC"
            )?.use { cursor ->
                val photos = mutableListOf<Image>()
                val idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
                while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    val id = cursor.getLong(idColumn)
                    val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id)
                    photos.add(Image(id, contentUri))
                }
                photos
            } ?: listOf()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[pic of working image gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWXMi.png)

As usual with my issues, it was something entirely different. The emulator bugged out, I reset it and uploaded images again and it works now. The code is a bit changed without the dispatcher now.

```
private fun loadImages(): List<Image>
    {
        val photos = mutableListOf<Image>()
        val uri = if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)
        } else MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        requireActivity().contentResolver.query(uri, arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID),
            null, null, null
        )?.use { cursor ->
            val idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
            while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                photos.add(Image(ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, cursor.getLong(idColumn))))
            }
            return photos.toList()
        } ?: return listOf()
    }
```

this is the code now, it works fine

Comment: what is in *Image class